# what value will be passed when i press the key a

Tags: c, signals, interrupt, interrupt-handling

When I press Ctrl+c then SIGINT will be passed to signal() . What value will be pass to the system call signal() when i press a key A ?

Comment: None, as you can't catch normal keys being pressed with signals.

Comment: Is there any reason for that ?

Comment: That's simply how it works. Technically speaking, just the combination `CTRL-C` doesn't really send a signal either, it's the shell program that catches that special key-code and sends the signal to your program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No signal will be raised.

The purpose of signals is to inform about a special condition outside normal program flow. Processing input, like the letter A, is part of normal program flow. These two are completely separate, and have different goals.

If you're on UNIX, type [`man signal`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/signal.3.html) on your console.